# Display scaling setting - difference between Gnome Tweaks and Gnome Display

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

Both tools seem to offer a way to change the scaling of the display, however it is not clear to me how they are related and which controls what. Also, they don't seem to be in sync.

What is the difference between these two tools?

[Gnome Tweaks and Gnome Display Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWwgx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The Scaling Factor in GNOME Tweaks scales only the fonts in the graphical user interface. The interface elements adjust to fit the text in if those elements are able of that. For example, if you change that scale, you can see that the size of the icons in panels do not change.

On the other hand, the Scale in the Displays section of GNOME Control Center scales the whole screen. Everything is scaled up, not just the fonts. This way the interface remains as the developer designed it, but scaled proportionally.

Comment: Setting the Scaling Factor in Tweaks has another important side-effect, which is that it will affect the default scale used by various applications like Firefox and Discord. For these applications, it affects more than just the font size. As such it could be preferable over just setting a bigger font size, in case setting 200% Scale for the screen is too much.